# Parse Cloudcode query error 141

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

If I run the Parse JavaScript code below locally, the query works fine. However, when I adapt the code to run as Parse cloudcode, the same query is not executed, and when I test the query content I get an error with code 141.

I have tested both functions at various points. The parameter comp_id and request.params.comp_id are the same.

**Parse JavaScript query (run locally, works fine)**

```
function testOne(comp_id) {
Parse.initialize(*****,*****);
    var Competition = Parse.Object.extend("Competition");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Competition);
    console.log(query);                      // <~ gets a valid query
    query.get(comp_id, {
        success: function(competition) {
            console.log(competition.id);
        },
        error: function(competition, error) {console.log(error);}
    });
}
```

**Parse cloudcode query (query does not execute, error 141)**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testOneCloud", function(request, response) {
    var comp_id = request.params.comp_id;

    var Competition = Parse.Object.extend("Competition");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Competition);
    msg = query;                               // <~ gets undefined error 141
    query.get(comp_id, {
        success: function(competition) {
            msg = competition.id;      // <~query success code does not get executed
        },
        error: function(competition, error) {console.log(error);}
    });

    response.success(msg);
});
```

Any idea why one of these two seemingly identical Parse programs work and the other doesn't?

Comment: They don't seem identical.  The second one refers to a msg variable that doesn't appear to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the undeclared msg variable is causing the problem.  How about (eliminating the extra variable and using promises):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testOneCloud", function(request, response) {
    var Competition = Parse.Object.extend("Competition");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Competition);
    query.get(request.params.comp_id).then(function(competition) {
        response.success(competition.id);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I think the msg variable was a red herring but the promises work. However, if I wanted to save how would I do it? I tried adding save code before response.success but it doesnt work?

Comment: OK, I figured that out - in my main program the above query is actually in an IF statement so I needed a response.success to be called for either part of the condition. Thanks!